# How to replace node ids with their respective properties?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-traversal

I am using `Neo4j` for graph database, and using Java to extract the path from it.
I have a path as follows:

```
[(3)--[KNOWS,5]-->(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)--[KNOWS,9]-->(6)--[KNOWS,10]-->(7)--[KNOWS,12]-->(9)]
```

I want to replace the node ids in the path with their property.
ex. For node id 3 with property `"name=ABC"`, output should come like `"[(ABC)--[KNOWS,5]....]"`
How it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the output we've shown is [Path.toString()](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.M05/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html). There is no direct way to configure a different way of output. However you can easily iterate over the path and create your own string representation of a Path:

```
String myCustomPathToString(Path path) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Node lastNode = null;
    for (PropertyContainer propertyContainer: path) {
       if (propertyContainer instanceof Node) {
          lastNode = (Node)propertyContainer
          Object default = lastNode.getId(); // as fallback
          sb.append("(").append(propertyContainer.getProperty("name", default).append(")");
       }
       if (propertyContainer instanceof Relationship) {
          Relationship rel = (Relationship)propertyContainer ;
          Object id = rel.getId();
          if (rel.getEndNode().equals(lastNode)) sb.append("<");
          sb.append("--[").append(rel.getType().name()).append(",").append(id).append("]--");
          if (rel.getStartNode().equals(lastNode)) sb.append(">");              
       }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

*DISCLAIMER*: I did not test the snippet above, so it's more a guidline than a working example.

Answer (score 1):

For Cypher you can use extract:

```
  START n=node:index(key="value")
  MATCH path=n-[:KNOWS*..5]-m
  RETURN extract(x in nodes(path) : x.name)
```

if you want to keep the relationships, you can do:

```
  RETURN extract(x in path : coalesce(x.name?,ID(x)+":"+type(x)))
```

see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/zvmyz